# BASH - how to force sleep of 300s before continuing the execution, if upon sending a curl post request the server returns an unexpected result

Tags: bash, curl, conditional-statements, sh

**@Socowi guided me to the perfect solution, you can see it at the bottom of the question:**

**(1)**
Here's a practical example of a script whose content consists of 10 curl POST requests, each will result in posting a different comment on my website.

```
#!/bin/bash

curl "https://mywebsite.com/comment... ...&text=Test-1"; sleep 60;
curl "https://mywebsite.com/comment... ...&text=Test-2"; sleep 60;
curl "https://mywebsite.com/comment... ...&text=Test-3"; sleep 60;
curl "https://mywebsite.com/comment... ...&text=Test-4"; sleep 60;
curl "https://mywebsite.com/comment... ...&text=Test-5"; sleep 60;
curl "https://mywebsite.com/comment... ...&text=Test-6"; sleep 60;
curl "https://mywebsite.com/comment... ...&text=Test-7"; sleep 60;
curl "https://mywebsite.com/comment... ...&text=Test-8"; sleep 60;
curl "https://mywebsite.com/comment... ...&text=Test-9"; sleep 60;
curl "https://mywebsite.com/comment... ...&text=Test-10"; sleep 60;
```

**(2)**
When that goes smoothly, here's how the terminal looks like:

[image: Text]

**(3)**
**The problem:** On random intervals something will go wrong, and instead of what's shown on the screenshot above, I will start getting large amounts of text containing words like "*Something went wrong*". For an example, it can execute the first 6 curl commands just fine, and on the 7th there will be a bad response... upon which the script continues further, and runs the 8th curl command and gets the same error shown in the terminal, and the script just goes on until the end leaving me with partially finished work.

**(4)**
**The solution desired:** I just want the script to pause/wait for 300 seconds whenever an error alike is thrown out in the terminal, before proceeding with running the next curl command in line in the script. The waiting does help, but I have to do it manually at the moment. Kindly help me with a solution how to properly modify my script to achieve the same.

Thank you !

**EDIT: The Solution for my problem as described, thanks to @Socowi:**

```
#!/bin/bash 
for i in {1..10}; do
  if curl "https://mywebsite.com/comment... ...&text=Test-$i" | grep -qF '"status":"ERROR"'; then
    sleep 300  # there was an error
  else
    sleep 60  # no error given
  fi
done

exec $SHELL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you could use `if curl ...` to check the exit status and adapt the sleeping time accordingly. However, in your case `curl` succeeds to get a response back. `curl` doesn't care about the content of the response, but you can check the content yourself. In your case a tool for json would be the proper way to parse the response, but a hacky `grep` does the job as well.
Since you want to print the response to the terminal, we use a variable, so that we can print the response *and* use `grep` on it.

```
#!/bin/bash 
for i in {1..10}; do
  response=$(curl "https://...&text=Test-$i")
  echo "$response"
  if grep -qF '"status":"ERROR"' <<< "$response"; then
    sleep 300 # there was an error
  else
    sleep 60  # everything ok
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you, I intentionally didn't post that almost identical version of my script which does include the loop hoping a solution would be more easily given for a more simple script :) So I suppose your example is literally everything I should have in my script, I will test it now on 9gag to be honest, the "error text" is unmeasureably shorter there when it happens hah.

Comment: The script just exists, even with exec $SHELL in the end, the terminal window closes :( I checked multiple times, the before-script works but yours just exits even though I didn't make any typo while changing the content of the curl. If you have the desire you can test it yourself and you'll fail too I presume, I'm now back on trying what could be the problem...

Comment: The line with the if statement should end with `then`, not `do`.

Comment: Bravo @WalterA , that solves it but I have to re-check the pauses, something was sus. I will check your answer too, silly me testing things in the most busy part of the day >.<

Comment: Update: Socowi's solution doesn't work for me. By looking at his example, even when "error" is thrown by 9gag upon trying to post a comment - which looks like this: {"code":"CODE_COMMENT_RATE_LIMIT","status":"ERROR","error":"You are doing that too much. Try again in 18 seconds.","payload":{"opUserId":"","quota":{"count":0,"wait":19}}}  - it will not wait for 300 seconds before running the next curl command, but it will wait for only 60 again.

Comment: Thank you @WalterA for fixing my little mistake. Elio Are you sure you get an actual error? From what you wrote it seems more like the website is returning something valid, but just not what you expected. In that case, you'd have to parse the output to decide whether the request worked or not. Please edit your question to include the actual URL and describe the problematic case in more detail so that we can try it for ourselves.

Comment: @Socowi, Correct. I do get a response in the terminal, but as you wrote "it's not what I expected" i.e. the comment wasn't successfully posted and hence the response I described in the previous comment . The real curl contains personal data which can be abused by anyone reading this. If you're real curious, you can post a comment on any 9gag post, and grab the only POST entry in the (Firefox please) browser's web developer tools by copying it as 'cURL (Windows)'. So now I need to follow this path - "you'd have to parse the output to decide whether the request worked or not." Thank you :|

Comment: Something hacky like `if curl ... | grep -qF '"status":"ERROR"'; then` could do the trick. For a full answer please **edit** your question.

Comment: I am looking right now for that here hah - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391945/check-if-the-particular-string-is-present-in-a-output-of-shell-script-using-shel - I did my best to describe the problem - in the terminal you'll see the time passed until each curl command gets successfully executed (as shown on screenshot) and you'll  see a huge text with "error" warnings like described under (3) I SINCERELY apologize for not having the proper vocabulary to explain it better, but at least you guided me to the right path.

Comment: @Socowi That did the trick, ran a full test on 9gag, the only downside (for which I won't complain at all) is the fact I'm not getting any textual response or time as shown on the screenshot in the question under (2), it just shows this - https://imgur.com/10HN2et . Now I'm editing my question and posting the answer there, and choosing your answer as a solution, just make sure to edit your answer as well based on what I'm about to insert in the question itself, so it'll all be legit and clearly visible for the future solution-seekers :) Bravo.

Comment: I adapted the answer so that the response is printed too.

Comment: @Socowi - Just switch the pauses like in my edit too otherwise it's incorrect. IF ERROR THEN 60 - is no good, should be 300 if error happens. Thank You again for your help, I further modified qrep to suit my needs.

Comment: Right. Sorry. Btw: You can edit other people's answers. Stackoverflow even encourages you to do so.

Comment: I tried but it displayed a "the queue for editing is full" warning XD